# Trying to combine like terms for a templated polynomial class using recursion in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, recursion, vector

I'm teaching my self C++.

I'm trying to combine polynomials. For this I have defined straightforward classes:
`Polynomial<T>`, `Term<T>` and `Coefficient<T>` (which may also just be
`complex<T>`) using simple value composition. I have defined the required operator overloads.

Polynomial's compare by sorting their terms (`std::sort`).

I am working on `combineLikeTerms()`; This method when called will first call
another member method that will sort this vector of Terms. For example:

```
4x^3 + 5x^2 + 3x - 4
```

would be a possible resulting sorted vector.

**Question**:

I am using two iterators on this vector and Im trying to merge adjacent terms
of the same *order*.

Lets say our initial vector after being sorted is this:

```
4x^3 - 2x^3 + x^3 - 2x^2 + x ...
```

after the function completes its iterations the temp stack vector would then
look like this 2x^3 + x^3 - 2x^2 + x ... if we look there are still like terms
this needs to be refactored again.

How do I do this? I'm thinking of using recursion.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// setPolynomialByDegreeOfExponent()
// should be called before combineLikeTerms
template <class T>
void Polynomial<T>::setPolynomialByDegreeOfExponent()
{
    unsigned int uiIndex = _uiNumTerms - 1;
    if ( uiIndex < 1 )
    {
        return;
    }
    struct _CompareOperator_
    {
        bool operator() ( math::Term<T> a, Term<T> b )
        {
            return ( a.getDegreeOfTerm() > b.getDegreeOfTerm() );
        } // operator()
    };
    stable_sort( _vTerms.begin(), _vTerms.end(), _CompareOperator_() );
} // setPolynomialByDegreeOfExponent

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// addLikeTerms()
template <class T>
bool Polynomial<T>::addLikeTerms( const Term<T>& termA, const Term<T>& termB, Term<T>& result ) const
{
    if ( termA.termsAreAlike( termB ) )
    {
        result = termA + termB;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} // addLikeTerms

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
// combineLikeTerms()
template <class T>
void Polynomial<T>::combineLikeTerms()
{
    // First We Order Our Terms.
    setPolynomialByDegreeOfExponent();
    // Nothing To Do Then
    if ( _vTerms.size() == 1 )
    {
        return;
    }
    Term<T> result; // Temp Variable
    // No Need To Do The Work Below This If Statement This Is Simpler
    if ( _vTerms.size() == 2 )
    {
        if ( addLikeTerms( _vTerms.at(0), _vTerms.at(1) )
    {
        _vTerms.clear();
            _vTerms.push_back( result );
        }
        return;
    }
    // For 3 Ore More Terms
    std::vector<Term<T>> vTempTerms; // Temp storage
    std::vector<Term<T>>::iterator it = _vTerms.begin();
    std::vector<Term<T>>::iterator it2 = _vTerms.begin()+1;
    bool bFound = addLikeTerms( *it, *it2, result );

    while ( it2 != _vTerms.end() )
    {
        if ( bFound )
        {
            // Odd Case Last Three Elems
            if ( (it2 == (_vTerms.end()-2)) && (it2+1) == (_vTerms.end()-1)) )
            {
                vTempTerms.push_back( result );
                vTempTerms.push_back( _vTerms.back() );
                break;
            }
            // Even Case Last Two Elems
            else if ( (it2 == (_vTerms.end()-1)) && (it == (_vTerms.end()-2)) )
            {
                vTempTerms.push_back( result );
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                vTempTerms.push_back( result );
                it += 2;    // Increment by 2
                it2 += 2;          "
                bFound = addLikeTerms( *it, *it2, result );
            }
            }
                else {
                // Push Only First One
                vTempTerms.push_back( *it );
                it++;   // Increment By 1
                it2++;         "
                // Test Our Second Iterator
                if ( it2 == _vTerms.end() )
                {
                    vTempTerms.push_back( *(--it2) );  // same as using _vTerms.back()
                }
                else
                {
                    bFound = addLikeTerms( *it, *it2, result );
                }
            }
        }
        // Now That We Have Went Through Our Container, We Need To Update It
        _vTerms.clear();
        _vTerms = vTempTerms;
        // At This point our stack variable should contain all elements from above,
        // however this temp variable can still have like terms in it.
        // ??? Were do I call the recursion and how do I define the base case
        // to stop the execution of the recursion where the base case is a
        // sorted std::vector of Term<T> objects that no two terms that are alike...
        // I do know that the recursion has to happen after the above while loop
    } // combineLikeTerms
```

Can someone help me find the next step? I'd be happy to hear about any bugs/efficiency issues in the code shown.
I love c++

Comment: Whoa. Perhaps you could word the question a bit more to the point. This is going to be TL;DR I fear. (Also, formatting helps)

Comment: Where is your polynomial class defined? Why isn't it stored internally as just a vector of its co-efficients? Does it need to be a template? Will its parameter type ever be anything other than double? Yeah, I see in your example the co-efficients are all ints but double makes more sense or is this "exercise of using templates".

Comment: I have taken the liberty of trimming the prose down a bit. I feel this will help people see the question.

Comment: @sehe i need to find a way to define a base case for recursion and the base case is when there are no more elements in std::vector<> that are alike.

Comment: @sehe ahh thank you that actually works, never posted here before

Comment: @CashCow yes it does, since the coeff class is templated and the in the coeff class its member is a std::complex the type will not be known at compile time. The need for the coeff class to be seperated as its own object is how my other classes are defined. Inside of the Term<T> class it has a Coefficient<T> object as a private member and two std::vectors as members: vector<char> and vector<unsigned int> this allows for all possible types of Terms in the polynomial class such as 3x^2y^3z - 3s^5t^3 - (12 - 2i)x^3 etc... It is a generic structure I am created to represent all possible Polynomials

Comment: @CashCow this way if someone is to use the templated class they can instantiate <int> <double> <float> etc as long as std::complex<> supports it

Comment: @sehe yeah, the main part I was looking for you kindof took out lol, I needed help on how to represent the base case of recursion, which is when there are no like terms.

Comment: Hey, never mind C++, just use SQL:
select sum(coefficient) group by term
(lol, but I guess this is what you are really trying to do)

Comment: @FrancisCugler I took it out because the way I read it you _asked whether recursion was the appropriate way here_. Sorry if that misrepresented your question. Regardless, I think you have two answers you should be able to proceed with

Comment: @FrancisCugler In C++ identifiers that started with `_` and followed by an upper case letter and identifiers that contain `__` are reserved for compiler developers and you should never use them. You have so many identifiers for your classes and functions, so why use something like `_CompareOperator_` that is forbidden by rules?

Comment: @BigBoss I got into the habit of naming all my member variables with a prefixed single underscore. all method and function names start with first word lowercase and each following word uppercase. all classes and structs start with a capital. I had to write a  struct _CompareOperator_  for the use of stable sort. And i am an independant writer, so for me nothing is really forbidden. Maybe one day I might end up writing my own programming language lol, huge task (not by myself of course but by my design.)

Comment: @BigBoss I could always do a throw back and post some ASM questions lol

Comment: @FrancisCugler: do you write your own compiler too? As long as you use an existing programming language and an existing compiler, some things *are* forbidden. Using names like this means you risk conflicting with names defined by the compiler or standard library. I'd like to see you tell your compiler that "for me, nothing is really forbidden, lulz". That's a moronic attitude

Comment: @jalf i know, i was being a bit sarcastic... but all my classes and members are inside of a namespace, and I do not use two underscores only 1 for member variables to a class or struct

Comment: @FrancisCugler You are free to use any non-sense code or identifier, but this is StackOverflow and here we help each other to improve programming skills. So if you want to do just do it, but if you are here to learn, so listen! If you use a compiler that use that identifier for a definition, nothing even namespaces can't protect you from a failure

Comment: @BigBoss yes, i do agree with you, and learning from those who are more experienced is a great way to improve. I do know that any prefixed double underscores are used by the compiler, as for members of my classes what would be a good suggestion, I like to have a good way to serparate textually members from local stack variables. I am always open for great advice... I never had anyone teach me, everything i've learned is self taught, other than a few tutorials. =^__^=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my take on it in modern C++.

Note the extra optimization of dropping terms with an *effective* coefficient of *zero*

Self contained sample: http://liveworkspace.org/code/ee68769826a80d4c7dc314e9b792052b

**Update: posted a c++03 version** of this **http://ideone.com/aHuB8**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Term
{
    T coeff;
    int exponent;
};

template <typename T>
struct Poly
{
    typedef Term<T> term_t;
    std::vector<term_t> _terms;

    Poly(std::vector<term_t> terms) : _terms(terms) { }

    void combineLikeTerms()
    {
        if (_terms.empty())
            return;

        std::vector<term_t> result;

        std::sort(_terms.begin(), _terms.end(), 
                [] (term_t const& a, term_t const& b) { return a.exponent > b.exponent; });

        term_t accum = { T(), 0 };

        for(auto curr=_terms.begin(); curr!=_terms.end(); ++curr)
        {
            if (curr->exponent == accum.exponent)
                accum.coeff += curr->coeff;
            else
            {
                if (accum.coeff != 0)
                    result.push_back(accum);
                accum = *curr;
            }
        }        
        if (accum.coeff != 0)
            result.push_back(accum);

        std::swap(_terms, result); // only update if no exception
    }
};

int main()
{
    Poly<int> demo({ { 4, 1 }, { 6, 7 }, {-3, 1 }, { 5, 5 } });

    demo.combineLikeTerms();

    for (auto it = demo._terms.begin(); it!= demo._terms.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << (it->coeff>0? " +" : " ") << it->coeff << "x^" << it->exponent;

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: A perfect piece of code (of course)! @FrancisCugler: This is a better fit with your existing code because the interface of `combineLikeTerms` here is exactly like yours. But the main point is the same as I described: No need for recusion and the like.

Comment: Your `combineLikeTerms: for()` should include `++first`, otherwise it won't work as expected.

Comment: @OlafDietsche oh, ah, hehe. Fixed by removing the second iterator at all, which was unneeded anyway. Less confusing this way :). Thanks

Comment: @FrancisCugler In case you needed help/reassurance this can be done in C++03: http://ideone.com/aHuB8

Comment: @jogojapan srry about that, im also having some trouble seeing the text, my monitor is dying, my new one should be here sometime from friday to monday. the pincuhsion isn't holding so my whole desktop looks like an hour glass and everything is skewed

Comment: @sehe I like your example above, however when i tried it, this line auto first = _vTerms.begin(), curr = first+1; was giving me this compiler/build error... 1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\advancedmathematics\polynomial.cpp(124): error C3538: in a declarator-list 'auto' must always deduce to the same type –

Comment: @FrancisCugler That seems strange, given that _vTerms would be a standard container. Anyways, you can trivially split the declarations. Or just use the [C++03 version](http://ideone.com/aHuB8) I provided.

Comment: @sehe I did this instead.. 'auto first = _vTerms.begin();  auto curr = first+1;'  and it compiled, build and ran, however for some reason when I check my variable with the numbers im using the last two are not being added. Ex: '3x^3 + 4x^3 +5x^2 + 3x + 6x' is giving me '7x^3 + 5x^2 + 3x + 6x' I will have to look into my code a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the polynomial as a sequence of pairs (coefficient,variable):

[(coefficient1,variable1),(coefficient2,variable2),(coefficient3,variable3),...]

As you describe, you iterate through this from left to right, combining two adjacent pairs into one whenever the *variable* part is identical (this of course assumes that the list has already been sorted by the *variable* part!).

Now what happens when there are *three or more* elements in this list that share their variables? Well, then just keep combining them. There is no need for recursion or anything complicated, really.

At any point during the iteration you combine the *variable* part of the current pair with the *variable* part **last seen**. If they are identical, you combine them and simply continue. If the next pair you get still has the same variable part as the one *last seen*, well then you combine them again. If you do this correctly, there shouldn't be any duplicates left.

Here is an example of how to do this. It works by creating a new pair list, then iterating through the input list, for each item of the input list it decides whether to either combine it with the item last pushed to the new list, or by adding a new element to the new list:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<std::pair<float,std::string>> Polynomial;

Polynomial combine_like_terms(const Polynomial &poly)
{
  if (poly.empty())
    return poly;

  /* Here we store the new, cleaned-up polynomial: */
  Polynomial clean_poly;

  /* Now we iterate: */    
  auto it = begin(poly);
  clean_poly.push_back(*it);
  ++it;
  while (it != end(poly)) {
    if (clean_poly.back().second == it->second)
      clean_poly.back().first += it->first; // Like term found!
    else
      clean_poly.push_back(*it); // Sequence of like-terms ended!
    ++it;
  }
  return clean_poly;
}

int main()
{
  Polynomial polynomial {
    { 1.0 , "x^2" },
    { 1.4 , "x^3" },
    { 2.6 , "x^3" },
    { 0.2 , "x^3" },
    { 2.3 , "x" },
    { 0.7 , "x" }
  };

  Polynomial clean_polynomial = combine_like_terms(polynomial);
  for (auto term : clean_polynomial)
    std::cout << '(' << term.first << ',' << term.second << ")\n";
  std::cout.flush();

  return 0;
}
```

You can easily make this templated again if you need to – I used `float` for the coefficients and `strings` for the variable part. It's really just a code example to show how this can be done easily without recursion or lots of iterators used in parallel.

Oh, and the code is written for C++11. Again, it's just a model and can be adjusted for C++03.

Comment: Ha. We think alike. I considered making that a non-mutating algorithm. But I elected to just go with the interface the OP described :)

Comment: very nice responses :)), however i do not have c++11 or vs 2012 :( im still on Vista lol.... :(  but atleast I still have the use of the auto keyword since im using 2010. Yeah, I thought there was an easier way then recursion, however, when I tried doing it with the two methods obove for some reason, I ended up adding one of the terms twice, and when I branched to using if statements then I had the problem if the size was even or odd. lol This should help alot :)